# Error in infinite sum

Tags: summation, series-expansion

The binary weight of the non negative integer k is defined by

```
w[k_] := Total[IntegerDigits[k, 2]]
```

The first values are (cf. http://oeis.org/ A000120)

```
Table[w[k], {k, 0, 10}]

(*
  {0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2}
*)
```

Now define formally the generating function

```
g[z_] = Sum[w[k] z^k, {k, 0, ∞}]

(*
  (2 - z)/(-1 + z)^2 
*)
```

Most surprisingly, *Mathematica* returns an explicit result.

But this can't be correct, as the expansions about z = 0 differ

```
Sum[w[k] z^k, {k, 0, 5}]

(*
  z + z^2 + 2 z^3 + z^4 + 2 z^5
*)

Series[(2 - z)/(-1 + z)^2, {z, 0, 5}] // Normal

(*
  2 + 3 z + 4 z^2 + 5 z^3 + 6 z^4 + 7 z^5
*)
```

It looks as if in the infinite sum the function `w[k]` is replaced by `(k + 2)`.

Any explanation? Seems to be a bug.

**EDIT #1**

24.02.15 19:08

To avoid the head replacement effect pointed out by belisarius we can consider the function

```
w1[n_] := n - Sum[IntegerExponent[k, 2], {k, 1, n}]
```

which is identical to w[k] for any k.

Now the infinite sum

```
g1[z_] = Sum[w1[n] z^n, {n, 0, \[Infinity]}]
```

is returned unevaluated, as it "should" (because it is too complicated)

$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty } z^n \left(n-\sum _{k=1}^n \text{IntegerExponent}[k,2]\right)$

So my discovery is not a bug, but I have learned the lesson that one should be very careful with infinite sums and their interpretation of the terms to be added.

Comment: Interestingly, Mathematica requires several seconds to compute `Sum[w[k] .1^k, {k, 0, 999999}]`, returning `0.112122`.  But `Sum[w[k] .1^k, {k, 0, 1000000}]` returns almost instantly with `2.34568`.  Yes, I would say that this is a bug.

Comment: Finite sums are computed by addition up to 10^6-1 terms. Above that symbolic methods are used by default. Per @belisarius explanation of `Total` behavior, and the procedural summation cutoff of a million, no bug here. On a related note, I think some information about this may be found in the documentation. Also mentioned in a prior MSE post, though offhand I do not recall which one that was.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I only remember [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/70063/193)

Comment: [This, I believe](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/59223/error-computing-sum-of-sum-of-digits)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is that `Total[]` works with **any** head. So:

```
Total[Derivative[1, 2, 1]]
(* 4 *)

Total[IntegerDigits[k, 2]]
(* 2 + k *)
```

And so you can expect

```
Sum[(2 + k) z^k, {k, 0, ∞}] == Sum[Total[IntegerDigits[k, 2]] z^k, {k, 0, ∞}]
```