# The sum of digits of Mersenne primes

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

I have problem to calculate the sum of digits of the mersenne primes $M_{57885161}$ , $M_{74207281}$ , and $M_{77232917}$. I'm not a 'computer guy', but I know that the sum of digits of $M_{82589933}$ is $111879913$. Could you help me ? Thanks.

Comment: I want to test the selfness of these mersenne primes, and therefore we need the sum of digits of these primes

Comment: $M_{82589933}$ is a self number.

Comment: Related: [(59223)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/59223/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this

```
Total@IntegerDigits[2^57885161 - 1]
```

> 78434761

```
Total@IntegerDigits[2^74207281 - 1]
```

> 100537543

```
Total@IntegerDigits[2^77232917 - 1]
```

> 104621260

or use this function

```
M[x_]:=Total@IntegerDigits[2^x-1]
M[82589933]
```

> 111879913